# Webdriver-Manager Start Certificate Error

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

I am getting the following error below when trying to start webdriver-manager.

It is working yesterday, after restarting it today, I am now getting a certificate error.

I enter --ignore_ssl, added proxy/https-proxy on User Variables and I already tried running the cmd as an administrator.

Error:

```
  C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm>webdriver-manager start --ignore_ssl 
  events.js:160
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^

  Error: unable to get local issuer certificate at Error (native)
      at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
      at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
      at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
```

When updating, I was able to update successfully without an error.

Comment: Please open a bug on github. If it is working with update then it should work with start. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed in webdriver-manager 12.0.5+:

This was an actual issue with webdriver-manager and was tracked as [issue #229](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/229). On start, webdriver-manager would check the cache and if the cache was old, it would replace it. The problem identified above is that the ignore_ssl and proxy flags were not being passed.

The real issue is that `webdriver-manager start` should not be making any web requests. Removing web requests removed the need to pass the ignore_ssl and proxy flags around. So if a user were to test their web app locally on an airplane, starting the selenium server should still work.

Anyway, this has been resolved in [PR #232](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/pull/232) and we should have a new release (12.0.5) later today.

### Update:

webdriver-manager version 12.0.5+ should have this fixed. The latest as of this update is 12.0.6. You can check what version you have installed with `webdriver-manager version`.

```
webdriver-manager version
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.5
[08:18:51] I/version - webdriver-manager 12.0.5
```

### Troubleshooting

Potential errors could include having an old installed global version although you have installed a project dependency with the correct webdriver-manager version.

How do I know `start` makes no web requests? Well, other than unit tests, I have tried this out by turning off wifi and trying `webdriver-manager start`. If `start` fails for you at this point with no internet, please check your version.

Comment: still getting an error.  

    C:\Users\<user>>webdriver-manager start
events.js:160  
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event  
          ^  

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com chromedriver.st
orage.googleapis.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)

C:\Users\<user>>webdriver-manager version
[16:07:45] I/version - webdriver-manager 12.0.5

Comment: This is a problem for me also, it was working fine for me last week, but since yesterday this error has started coming up and I can no longer get my selenium server launching. I already have 12.0.5 installed. @PaulCo - did you get past this?

Comment: @mindparse - nope, I always reinstall protractor (npm deleted) everytime I encountered the issue.

Comment: @mindparse open up a github issue. I'll take a look at it this week hopefully. Also updating the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

webdriver-manager start --ignore_ssl

this will work for you.

Comment: This is not a real answer. While it may, or may not, solve the issue, you need to add more context and explanation on what the original issue was and how your solution resolves it.